# Are MySQL/MariaDB and Postgresql compatible?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database, mariadb, web-applications

I want to install multiple applications on my web server. For most of them, using PostgreSQL is possible or the only option. But in one of them's installation guide, only MariaDB is mentioned. If I create a PostgreSQL database, will it work on the software that only talks about MariaDB too?

Comment: No, you need the correct software installed, a software use library to connect to the correct database, even the SQL query are not 100% identical.

Comment: mariadb and MySQL may be compatible but psql nope never